# Video in Beamer with multimedia, undefined control sequence

Tags: beamer, errors, presentations, animations

> ./demo.vrb:4: Undefined control sequence.  \pdfmark 
>                       [{\box \@tempboxa }]{pdfmark=/ANN,Subtype=/Movie,Movie=<... l.4
>   ...[width=\textwidth]{CNT2.png}}{CNTvideo.mov}

this is the error that I get when trying to compile my beamer presentation in overleaf.

here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{m}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{CNTs-Bioimaging and Functionalization}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
\movie[loop]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{CNT2.png}}{CNTvideo.mov}
\scriptsize{YouTube,. 'Deep Tissue Anatomical Imaging Of Mice With Carbon Nanotube Fluorophores In NIR II'. N.p., 2015. Web. 24 Nov. 2015.}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.55\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{CNT3.png}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I can't understand what is the problem since the `multimedia`package is uploaded and all the field options of `\movie` are filled.
Could it be due to my template? In case here is the link

> https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-modern-beamer-theme-metropolis/qzyvdhrntfmr#.VmlD-_nhDIU

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error and I was using XeLaTeX, which apparently doesn't support multimedia. I switched to LuaLaTeX and finally got a working movie in Okular.